# NH 3.2 Fluent Mapping Lazy Loading

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I used NH 3.2 mapping by code and I tryied Nhibernate Mapping Generator http://nmg.codeplex.com/ which looked a great tool.

I found a big difference between my code and theirs. On each class they have a call to the function LazyLoad(). (Although I thinked that it was the default behaviour)

Now I fear that my application doesn't use lazy loading, does someone know the default behaviour of nh 3.2 with mapping by code ? (when we don't call the LazyLoad method)

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the `default-lazy` attribute of the `hibernate-mapping` tag which can be changed in Fluent NHibernate by adding the `DefaultLazy.Always()` or `DefaultLazy.Never()` convention.

If no `default-lazy` attribute is defined (no convention added in Fluent NHibernate), lazy loading is enabled.